# Sessão diferente em abas do navegador

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet, session

Estou com problemas quanto a sessão de um sistema. O que ocorre é o seguinte:

1. Abri o navegador, acessei a URL do sistema e fiz login. Nesse ponto a sessão "X" é criada.
2. Abri uma nova aba do navegador, acessei a URL e fiz login com outro usuário.
3. Retornei para a primeira aba, abri outras telas do sistema e nesse momento a minha aba 01 assume a sessão da 02.
4. O ajuste tem que ser feito porque o sistema de homologação e de produção são constantemente utilizados em paralelo e por isso não podem "misturar" as sessões.

Dados Extras:

- Não importa quantas abas eu acesse e com qual login eu acesse o sistema, a sessão atual será SEMPRE do último login efetuado.
- As telas que citei no item 3 são janelas com o componente [Window da Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index)
- O problema ocorre em TODOS os navegadores.
- Os sistemas de homologação e produção ficam no mesmo servidor.

Comment: Isabela, o problema esta ao efetuar o login, você não deve estar checando se existe sessão de login ativa, evitando que o usuário acesse a rota de login, e assim redirecionando ele. Ao efetuar o login sempre um login irá sobscrever o outro pois os sessions name são os mesmos. Se o problema estar o sistema de homologação interferindo no de produção o problema esta na definição da session, você não diz qual url ele pertence, ele deve estar pegando todo dominio.

Comment: @juniorb2ss eu percebi que o nome das sessões são o mesmo, mas não tem como eu trocar esse nome então? E como eu valido se não tem sessão ativa? Nas minhas contas, não era pra ele estar compartilhando a sessão porque uma nova aba em teoria seria uma nova instância, certo?

Comment: Não, Isabela. Irei postar uma resposta, aguarde.

Comment: Acho que é mais problema de filtro @Isabela, estou acostumado com Java, não sei se PHP tem esse recurso implementado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resposta curta

No arquivo de login, fazer algo assim:

```
<?php

switch( $ambiente )
{
  case "Produção";
    session_name( "SESSIDSistemaX");
    break;
  case "Homologação":
    session_name( "SESSIDSistemaXHom" );
    break;
}
session_start();
```

Ou o equivalente na linguagem que estás usando.

### Explicação

Já que tem duas "aplicações" rodando num mesmo servidor, sob um mesmo domínio, o jeito é isolar o alterar o **nome** do cookie de sessão.

### Resposta longa

Em algum ponto do código é aberta uma sessão a partir de um cookie de nome específico. Se esse cookie estiver vazio uma nova sessão é iniciada com um novo id, senão a sessão com o mesmo id contido no cookie que será aberta/criada.

Quando há dois servidores separados as sessões não se misturam por indisponibilidade pura: um servidor não acessa os arquivos do outro. Quando há dois domínios (ou sub domínios) é possível tentar a solução apontada por @juniorb2ss, pois cookies podem ser restritos por domínios inteiros e parciais, o que na prática faz o navegador não entregar cookie de um domínio em outro, ainda que na mesma máquina, o que força a abertura de uma nova sessão, com um cookie que não é compartilhado.

Mas quando não se está em máquinas separas, nem em domínios separados, então sempre abre a mesma sessão. E é obvio pelo algoritmo acima: a pasta de onde o `session_start()` é chamado não altera o seu comportamento. Pelo contrário, se alterasse, provavelmente não funcionaria.

Então não existem "dois sistemas" rodando em pastas separadas de uma mesma máquina, sob o mesmo domínio. Do ponto de vista da linguagem, são dois códigos em pastas diferentes de uma mesma aplicação que estão abrindo uma mesma sessão.

### Isso eventualmente vai dar problema

Quem avisa amigo é. Rodar "sistemas" diferentes em pastas de um mesmo servidor, em um mesmo domínio, é pedir para dar problema. A solução acima, embora funcione, é um quebra galho consideravelmente frágil.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema pode estar perante ao compartilhamento de cookie.

Vamos partir do principio que a `URL` de `produção` sua veja p.x: `prod.url.com` e o de `homologação` seja `homo.url.com`. Ok?

Ao setar um cookie, ele esta sendo setado para `.url.com` ou seja, ele ficará persistente tanto em `prod.url.com` ou `homo.url.com` que são `sub-dominios` de `url.com`. Acompanhou?

O PHP te da possibilidade de setar o cookie para domínio:

```
setcookie('YourCookieName', 'Some Values', time() + 3600, '/', 'url.com');
```

Esta forma o cookie sera setado apenas para `url.com`

```
setcookie('YourCookieName', 'Some Values', time() + 3600, '/', '.url.com');
```

Esta forma o cookie sera setado para `url.com` e sub-domínios.

Para setar um cookie para um sub-domínio especifico, que é o que você esta precisando basta fazer:

```
setcookie('YourCookieName', 'Some Values', time() + 3600, '/', 'homo.url.com');
```

Desta forma ao acessar `home.url.com` você estará logado, ao acessar `prod.url.com` você precisará fazer o login novamente.

Bom, é o máximo que posso te analisar, pois você não postou código, então acredito que seja o que esteja acontecendo.

## Edit

Se você não esta trabalhando com sub-domínios, ou seja, com paths p.x: `url.com/prod` ou `url.com/homo` ai é outra questão, já que para o server são sistema iguais.

Eu fico devendo uma solução global para este tipo, até porque evito ao máximo trabalhar com sistemas distintos separados por paths, sempre procuro trabalhar com sub-domínios, a integridade é maior.

Se você trabalha assim a melhor forma é você no login definir qual sistema o usuário esta efetuando login. Por exemplo salvar na session dele

```
$_SESSION['ambiente'] = 1 // url.com/prod
```

Ao verificar se o login do usuário esta ativo você pergunta qual o ambiente dele, é para `URL` que ele esta visitando? Se não for você força o logout para renovar o login dele para aquele ambiente.

Para maiores explicações só vendo o código, é máximo que consigo.

Abraços.